# PJSIP Android Build NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, pjsip

I'm Getting a error this error when i use ndk-build in pjsip example

```
Compile++ thumb  : pjsua2 <= pjsua2_wrap.cpp
In file included from /Documents/softphones/trunk-pjproject/pjproject/pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/../output/pjsua2_wrap.cpp:160:0:
/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b//platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:592:13: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
/Documents/softphones/trunk-pjproject/pjproject/pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/../output/pjsua2_wrap.cpp: In constructor 'Swig::Director::JNIEnvWrapper::JNIEnvWrapper(const Swig::Director*)':
/Documents/softphones/trunk-pjproject/pjproject/pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/../output/pjsua2_wrap.cpp:335:73: error: invalid conversion from 'void**' to 'JNIEnv** {aka _JNIEnv**}' [-fpermissive]
/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b//platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:1072:10: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'jint _JavaVM::AttachCurrentThread(JNIEnv**, void*)' [-fpermissive]
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/pjsua2/__/output/pjsua2_wrap.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas how fix it ?
I'm using MacOs
swig -version

SWIG Version 3.0.7

Compiled with g++ [x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0]

Configured options: +pcre

Thanks You!

Comment: having same problem :(. have you fixed it?

Comment: is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have compile issue with new Android NDK too. The way I solved is downgrade NDK version.

You can go to https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html and download Revision 13b (October 2016). Extract files to ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

And my SWIG version is 3.0.12 (I don't think this matters).

Hope this helps you.